# Width of div changes when position becomes fixed from relative

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The width of the div "topNav" changes by few pixels when its position style is changed from relative to fixed. I found a jquery plugin (http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/) which can perform the same functionality I'm looking for elegantly, but I feel it is a overkill for this purpose.

EDIT: My question is how to avoid changing the div sizes.

Check out the code at :

http://jsbin.com/azace5/edit

Comment: What is the functionality you are looking to implement elegantly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the page's "default margin". This will do it in "every browser":

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
```

**See:** http://jsbin.com/azace5/2

Answer (score 0):

Or you can add a minimum width.

```
min-width:600px;
```

Comment: use the % for width and specify a fixed min-width.