# Prevent div from changing size when parent div becomes fixed in Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, zurb-foundation-5

I have some nested DIVs, on my page. Inside the content area, I have a row defined, with two DIVs (left DIV is 3 columns and right DIV is 9 columns). I want the left DIV to be sticky at the top of the page when I scroll. My code is working, however when my div sticks to the top of the browser, for some reason the DIV changes width. I can't explain why.

```
CSS
@media only screen and (min-width: 40.063em) {
  .my-sticky-element.stuck {
    position: fixed;
    top: 5px;
  }
}

JS
var stickyElement = $('.my-sticky-element');
var vTop = stickyElement.offset().top - parseFloat(stickyElement.css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (y >= vTop) {
    stickyElement.addClass('stuck');
  } else {
    stickyElement.removeClass('stuck');
  }
});

HTML
<div class="row">
  <div class="medium-3 columns">
    <div class="my-sticky-element">
      <div class="box-body radius bg-white clearfix">
        <div class=" filter" style="padding-bottom: .5rem;">
          <i class="fa fa-filter fa-2x text-black"></i>
          <input id="contactFilter" type="search" placeholder="Filter by Contact Name" style="margin-bottom: .5rem;" />
          <a href="#" class="right selectAllContacts"><i class="fa fa-square-o fa-2x"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="medium-9 columns">
    <div class="box-body no-padding" style="">
      <!--- content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems that `.my-sticky-element.stuck` causes the div to shrink in width. I have not written the full CSS, however I have observed that before the DIV becomes sticky it is `position:relative` and after it becomes stuck it is `position:fixed`.

Comment: can you make a fiddle of your code..???

Comment: Are you looking for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364437/width-of-div-changes-when-position-becomes-fixed-from-relative?rq=1

Comment: I think it's because you changing the.. what do you call it.. the "position layer"? I mean it looks like you using some kind of responsive design, but when you change the position from relative to fixed, it also changes the layer and the 3-9 Layer is split up to a 3 fixed and a 9 relative layer. At this point the row has no (or just a different) parent element which where it gets the width property. Could I describe what I mean? :D

Comment: dsaket - I had seen this solution, and tried it before posting my question, however it did not resolve my problem

Comment: Cagatay Ulubay - First, you are correct, I am using a responsive design. Second, I would say you are right about the 3-9 split. But I don't know how to get around that.

Comment: dsaket - sorry, I have never used JSFIDDLE before. I just tried setting up an account, and creating a fiddle, but don't see how to add all the JS (Foundation and a couple other plugins) that I use on the page.